# Use a between statement as a group

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I'm having a hard time finding the words to describe my problem, so Google is not turning up any results.  Sorry for what is (probably) a very simple question.

Basically I want to have two rows, both of which are created by individual between statements.  I've tried using an "AS" statement like I would in a Select, but that just gives me a syntax error.

Here's my code:

```
Select      WEEK_ID,
            SUM (CUR_CHARGE_UNITS) as "Pro Units"
From        DW******.SLS****
Where       (WEEK_ID Between '201201' And '201252') --Use 'as' statement here?
            Or (WEEK_ID Between '201101' And '201152')
Group By    WEEK_ID
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to make

`WEEK_ID Between '201201' And '201252'`

collapse into one row titled "2012".  Like I said, all I've tried is

`(WEEK_ID Between '201201' And '201252) As "2012"`

Any thoughts?  Any tutorials anyone wants to point me at?  Any insults for not knowing the answer to a presumably basic question?

Comment: something like `group by substr(week_id, 0, 4)`, whatever your db's equivalent of the substring function is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try taking the first 4 characters and grouping by that instead:

```
Select      LEFT(WEEK_ID,4) AS Year,
            SUM (CUR_CHARGE_UNITS) as "Pro Units"
From        DW******.SLS****
Where       (WEEK_ID Between '201201' And '201252') --Use 'as' statement here?
            Or (WEEK_ID Between '201101' And '201152')
Group By    LEFT(WEEK_ID,4)
```

The benefit is that LEFT is ANSI so should work in all rdbms

Comment: +1 . . . But you should really called left(week_id, 4) `year` and not `week`.

Comment: Is OP actually asking about substringing?  It looks to me like he wants to alias a set of columns.

Comment: This solution actually gets the job done.  It doesn't do it in the way I would have preferred, but no matter :-).

Comment: I read the line - collapse into one row titled "2012" - as meaning he only wants one row for 2012 rather than a separate column to indicate the year

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a case statement

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Fpsmcse.htm

```
select
    case when week_id between '201201' and '201252'
              then '2012'
          when week_id between '201101' and '201152'
              then '2011'
     end as 'year'
        SUM (CUR_CHARGE_UNITS) as "Pro Units"
From        DW******.SLS****
Where       (WEEK_ID Between '201201' And '201252')
        Or (WEEK_ID Between '201101' And '201152')
Group By 
     case when week_id between '201201' and '201252'
              then '2012'
          when week_id between '201101' and '201152'
              then '2011'
     end
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Case statements in SQL.  I think I'll need to read into this as it probably would prove useful.

Comment: You can group by a case statement if it's in your select but don't use an alias in the grouping.. SELECT CASE x END AS 'Year' FROM y GROUP BY CASE x END. CASE is not ANSI though so you'll have to check with your RDBMS vendor first

Comment: CASE here is splitting the values into new **columns** rather than **rows** as the question asks for.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of "any thoughts", I would suggest that you simply study the GROUP BY clause and the concept of SQL aggregates.

If you want to aggregate all weeks of the year, then you *don't* want to select or group by WEEK_ID (you'll want to group by **year**).